# Statements that can be reordered

Tags: c++

Suppose we have the following three code snippets:

1. ```
   // both a and b are non-volatile ints
   a = 123;
   b = 456;
   ```
2. ```
   // both a and b are non-volatile ints
   a = rand();
   b = rand();
   ```
3. ```
   cout << "foo" << endl;
   cout << "bar" << endl;
   ```

From what I understand, the statements in (1) can be reordered by compilers, while those in (2)(3) can't, because that would change the observable behavior of the program.

But *how* do compilers know when things can't be reordered when they are not so "obviously" dependent (statements like `++a; b = a * 2;` are obviously dependent), as in (2)(3)? E.g., maybe certain things like non-`constexpr` function invocation would prevent reordering...?

Comment: Without knowing for absolute certain, my gut feel would be that dependence between both 2 and 3 would be easily observable by the compiler. This is because `rand()` uses a mathematical formula to generate the next random value in a sequence. As such, there is a side-effect to `a = rand()` where some internal state is updated, to which `b = rand()` depends - hence no reordering. Similarly `cout` will likely end up in a system call which can't be reordered.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only standard rule that governs reordering (and optimization in general) is the "as if" rule, meaning that the compiler can do anything that it pleases if it determines that the end result is the same, and the standard won't get in the way. However, when we get to that level, the compiler probably no longer operates on the C++ source level: it's probably dealing with an intermediate form, and thinking in statements might not actually best reflect what is going on.

For instance, in your second example:

```
// both a and b are non-volatile ints
a = rand();
b = rand();
```

The compiler could call `rand` twice and store the result of the second `rand` call to `b` before storing the result of the first `rand` call to `a`. In other words, the assignments have been reordered but the calls haven't. This is possible because the compiler optimizes a representation of your program that is more granular than C++.

Various compilers use various tricks to determine whether two intermediate representation instructions can be reordered, but most often, function calls are insurmountable barriers that cannot be reordered. Especially, calls to external libraries (like `rand`) can't even be analyzed and are certain to not be reordered since the compiler will prefer a conservative but known-correct approach.

In fact, function calls can only be reordered if the compiler determines that they cannot interfere with one another. Compilers attempt to solve this problem with alias analysis. The idea is that beyond value dependence (for instance, in `a * b + c`, the `+` operation depends on the result of `a * b` and thus `a * b` must happen first), ordering (almost) only matters when you write somewhere and read back from there later. This means that if you can correctly identify every memory operation and their impact, you can determine if two memory operations can be reordered, or even eliminated altogether. For these purposes, a call is considered a big memory operation that encompasses all the smaller loads and stores that it does.

Unfortunately, the general case of alias analysis is known to be uncomputable. While compilers get smarter and smarter, you'll probably never have a compiler that is systematically able to make the best decision on call reordering even if you had all of the source code that you link against.

Some compilers have attributes specific to themselves that govern whether they should consider the function safe for reordering, regardless of their own analysis. For instance, gcc will happily reorder, cache or even eliminate function calls with the `[[gnu::pure]]` attribute if it thinks that it will lead to a performance increase.

Answer (score 1):

In order to reliably satisfy the requirements of the standard, a compiler may only re-order statements when they are "obviously" *not* dependent.

If it's not sure, it can't re-order. So there is no problem.

Comment: Is there a definition in the standard for "obviously" not dependent?

Comment: provable. Whoever codes the statement, will have to make sure that he has caught all cases. Otherwise, he produces a buggy compiler, and he won't live long in the market.

Comment: @ZizhengTai: The definition is in English. It's like saying I am only allowed to pull out onto a roundabout when there are "obviously" no cars coming — you don't need a definition of the term to know what that means, and to know what happens when it turns out I wasn't actually sure after all. How a compiler implements this is extremely complicated and out of the scope of a Stack Overflow question. However, you could enrol on a four-year PhD in compilers to find out :)

Answer (score 0):

Reordering of instructions appears "only" in cases where single-threaded program behavior does not change.